# Can not use BindingAdapter in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I used to create `DataBindingAdapter` for creating custom xml attributes in data binding.

```
object DataBindingAdapter {
    @BindingAdapter("android:src")
    fun setImageByRes(imageView: ImageView, @DrawableRes resId: Int) {
        imageView.setImageResource(resId)
    }
}
```

It was **working well** **in Java**. **But not working** **in kotlin**.

As I understand object in kotlin are similer to static method of Java. But its not working in data binding.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required DataBindingComponent is null in class FragmentBottomBarBinding. A BindingAdapter in
>   acr.browser.lightning.utils.DataBindingAdapter is not static and
>   requires an object to use, retrieved from the DataBindingComponent. If
>   you don't use an inflation method taking a DataBindingComponent, use
>   DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent or make all BindingAdapter methods
>   static.

Comment: have you tried `@JvmStatic` annotation on `setImageByRes`.

Comment: If you're facing interop problems (Java calling Kotlin code), a good approach is to decompile the generated bytecode to Java and see how the result looks. This often makes it immediately clear where the interface mismatches.

Comment: @Moinkhan JvmStatic did the trick.

Comment: You forgot @JvmStatic

Comment: Because you did not answer, so I did your work. You can now answer. I will mark it right, You deserve it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just add the **`@Jvmstatic`** annotation on `setImageByRes` method.

```
object DataBindingAdapter {
    @BindingAdapter("android:src")
    @JvmStatic
    fun setImageByRes(imageView: ImageView, @DrawableRes resId: Int) {
        imageView.setImageResource(resId)
    }
}
```

as per the `@Jvmstatic` [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-static/index.html)

> Specifies that an additional static method needs to be generated from this element if it's a function. If this element is a property, additional static getter/setter methods should be generated.

In short method declared in one place and used from multiple languages of JVM. If you're calling a method from Java, then you should declare it as @JvmStatic, because adding the @JvmStatic annotation in one place will allow you to leave out multiple .Companion references in multiple places.

Comment: If you add a little info about JvmStatic for new comers, that will be great.

Comment: Hi @Moinkhan how to link this DataBindingAdapter with recycler view or adapter ?

Answer (score 7):

No. Object in kotlin is same like singleton. I think u dont need put it in Object. Just make new file lets say `BindingAdapters.kt` and u dont need write any class or object keywords.

It should look like this. Nothing else. If u need more functions just add it below this one. Again no class keyword or brackets are needed. It will be global function. Maybe u should also use `ContextCompat` for getting `resource` properly with context from `imageView`. And i would rather name it differently than *android:src*. What about imageResBinder

```
@BindingAdapter("imageResBinder")
fun setImageByRes(imageView: ImageView, @DrawableRes resId: Int) {
    imageView.setImageResource(resId)
}
```

and after that in your `.xml` file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    style="@style/Image.SomeImageStyle"
    app:imageResBinder="@{viewModel.getImageRes()}" />
```

Comment: If I need, How can I call this function from another kotlin?

Comment: U cant. Only thing u can is to call it from different .xml file because its global method only for databinding. So u cant lets say call it in fragment onViewCreated(). Of course u can make a static class for loading resources but i think u should not if u are using databinding. U can also put this bindingAdapter only into some model class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40845767/where-to-place-android-bindingadapter-method

Comment: Then I will prefer @JvmStatic because there can be some common function which can be useful to call from another activity also.